# Apache2 Ubuntu Server Failed to connect to localhost port 5984: Connection refused with CouchDB

Tags: database, connection, apache2, couchdb

I have an Apache2 Ubuntu Server that is running and want to replicate my couchDB database locally to remote on the server. With terminal *curl* from this [documentation on how to replicate](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_replicate_a_database). I performed this:

```
 curl -X POST -d '{"source":"http://127.0.0.1:5984/demo","http://server_IP_here/":"demo"}' \http://127.0.0.1:5984/_replicate
```

The error comes up everytime. Is there something wrong with the above statement?
The server IP has doesn't require ports as a side not.

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 5984: Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use port **8092**
I couldn't found documentation on this, though random trying different ports found that my couchbase instance answer there :)